# perl "kill 0" command works via .pl script, and command line, but not via browser

Tags: perl, kill-process

maddened here: the code in my .pl script runs successfully via the command line in these ways:

```
perl 5_pidfiletest.pl
perl -e 'do "5_pidfiletest.pl"'
```

and, also the heart of the script, here, runs fine via command line:

```
perl -e 'my $pid=10020; my $running = $pid ? kill 0, $pid : undef;print $running;'
```

NOTE: it reads a pid file[i hard code the file with the # of a process running that has an id of 10020]. it reads the #, then checks if the process is running. if it is, it leaves the file alone. if the process with that same # is not running, it creates another .pid file with a new number.

NOTE: i must run the script as the same user as the owner of the process.

*yet*, when i call the .pl file via $.ajax [$.ajax({ url: 'cgi-bin/perlFuncs.pl', ...], all code in the "perlFuncs.pl" runs fine, *except* the "kill 0" ignores the process it is testing.

code for .pl script:

```
my $pidfile = '/opt/myid/logs/testCron.pid';
if ( -e $pidfile ) {
    open( FH, "<$pidfile" );
    my $pid = <FH>;
    close FH;
    #for testing file-exists, hard code $pid to a running process, say "top"
    $pid = 10020;    #hard code, so that it will look for process 10020["top"]

    warn "Pid file Exists with pid: $pid";

    ##### HEART OF THE CODE #####
    my $running = $pid ? kill 0, $pid : undef;

    if ($running) {
        warn "Pid file Exists with pid: $pid and process was still running";

    } else {
        warn "Pid file Exists with pid: $pid, but appears process is no longer running, so creating another pid.";
        open( my $fh, "+>$pidfile" ) or warn("[CRITICAL] Fatal - Can not create pidfile $pidfile");
        warn "Pid file created $$";
        print $fh $$;
        close $fh;
    }

} else {
    warn "Pid file DOES NOT exist, going to create";
    open( my $fh, "+>$pidfile" ) or warn("[CRITICAL] Fatal - Can not create pidfile $pidfile");
    warn "Pid file created $$";
    print $fh $$;
    close $fh;
    warn "### >>> END OF PID CHECK <<< ###";
}
```

THAT code in a .pl file by itself runs fine, detects the process 10020 running.
when it is called via the $.ajax url it does not properly "kill 0" the process. NOTE: "kill 0" is just a test, does not kill the job. typically, if one does not have permissions to send a signal, it will also ignore the process as if it is not running. *YET*, the code calling the .pl file via $.ajax if the same owner as the process. the $.ajax code:

```
function getData() {                        //function getData
$.ajax({
    url: 'cgi-bin/perlFuncs.pl',            //ajax call to cgi-bin/ajaxFuncs.pl
    data:  ({ ajaxAction: 'getDBInfo'}),    //call handle is getDBInfo
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
```

whoever can solve this one, name your price! my troubleshooting matrix and deadline are running out of options! [thx for your time!!]

Comment: You are certain your target process is running as the HTTP server user? That is what the CGI will execute as, regardless of the file ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Perl script is running as a CGI, so it was run by `fork+pipe+exec` from an Apache child process (or some other HTTPD), which means it will have inherited signal handlers from the parent HTTP server process which are likely blocking or handling the signal.

EDIT: Oops, I failed to notice you are using kill 0. This argument may not apply.

Even so, anytime I've run into issues like this, I look into the mechanics of executing a CGI, and look at traits of the parent process.

Secondly, it isn't clear that you've stated that your target process is running as the same user as the HTTP server (commonly "apache" or "nobody" for example). Unless you've configured setuid scripts, or are running suEXEC, or otherwise overridden it in your httpd.conf, your CGI will run as the default "apache" user, regardless of the owner of the file. Check your httpd.conf file and you'll find something like:

```
User apache
Group apache
```

Comment: actually, i do not know this, so thx for stating it! so, my code is owned by admin01, my id is myid01. i sudo into admin01 and start process "top" which has [been running a while, as] id 10020, so its owner is "admin01". since my code is owned by admin01, i presume[d] when running it via http, that it ran as admin01. that's why i started the process as admin01, so my admin01 code would try the "kill 0" on an admin01 process. [note: the kill 0 is just testing if process is running]. ok FFwd: if Apache uid is "root", i suppose i'd have to figure out how to do "kill 0" as root. [?]. many thx!

Comment: Not, root. Apache starts as root to bind to port 80, and the orginal parent process may show up as root, but it will spawn processes to handle http requests that will set their userid to a less privileged user. It is configured in the httpd.conf with User and Group parameters.

Comment: The permissions on your script file are only relevant as far as whether its permissions allow the web user to execute it. The script runs as the id of whoever starts it (except in case of setuid scripts). Ideally your web user can read and execute the script, but not write it.

Comment: according to /etc/ps -ef --forest | less, it appears some entities run as "root"[parent], others as my userid, some as "apache". httpd.conf does show "User apache, and Group apache" but i don't see anything else relevant. re: allow CGI scripts, my app already runs .pl files from cgi-bin; and "ExecCGI" seems like simply the ability to execute cgi, which of course is enabled. direction: looking to run command [do 'kill0.pl';] as the user whose process is running. seems like only option at this point. THX for all your ideas! more clues, feel free to share :).[at some pt i will +1 one of yours]

Comment: Hrm, I'd have to actually see what you are trying to accomplish, and your env to give you much more guidance. Perhaps (actually likely) your hosting provider has configured a module to provide more secure CGI execution. I suggest emailing them your issue to get more details on the execution environment. They should provide that to you.

Comment: one idea i heard is "run the script as the user of the process owner using setuid". [>>"Operation not permitted"<<]. so, next step is to lay this at manager's feet; meanwhile, show the code works within the context of user to user [via cmd line, it does "kill 0" as user X against process owner X]. many thanks, codenheim!!! i do not know how to officially compliment in this forum other than +1 an answer/let me know if you need anything.